# Spring Boot Unable to load class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I've created a new Spring Boot project. I'm trying to setup a DataSource to use MSSQL. However I seem to be getting the error "Unable to load class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

I've placed the file jdbcsql4.jar in a folder in my project /lib/jdbcsq4.jar

In my pom.xml file I've added the following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I have an application.properties file, and I'm defining the database credentials like this:

```
secondary.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1:50109
secondary.datasource.username = sa
secondary.datasource.password = mypassword
secondary.datasource.driver-class-name =     com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Can anyone possibly indicate where I may be going wrong?

Comment: When you down vote my question, is there any chance you could explain why? How else am I supposed to improve my questions?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this issue by following the instructions in this link http://claude.betancourt.us/add-microsoft-sql-jdbc-driver-to-maven/

EDIT:
The original link above no longer exists, but here's a similar link.
http://biercoff.com/add-microsoft-sql-jdbc-driver-to-maven/

Comment: The page doesn;t exist. Will be great help if you can explain briefly - or some other pointers

Comment: I've added another link as it seems the original link I posted no longer exists

Answer (score 3):

For the ppl who facing these issue.
Add dependency in POM. 
Microsoft finally made the driver available on the Maven Central Repository.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
 <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
 <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

you can check here.
[Microsoft link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/)

Comment: 'Microsoft finally made the driver available...' note that the blog post to which you refer is almost 3 years old, not as old as the question but still old :-)